# Compile error Missing \endcsname inserted. <to be read again>

Tags: errors, compiling

Please I have no idea what's wrong with the code I've been trying everything.

```
./main.aux:9: Missing \endcsname inserted. <to be read again> \unhbox 
l.9 \newlabel{tab:Correlaci\IeC {\'o}n}{{1}{3}}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please post a small, complete document which we can try to compile to reproduce the error. Right now, it is hard to say much which might be helpful. However, if you are using special characters in labels, replace them and remove the `.aux` file and then try re-compiling.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot use a command such as `\'e` in the argument of a `\label{}`. Not, at least, without doing some kind of special TeX acrobatics.

For example, something like `\label{tab:a\'ea}` will produce an error roughly of the kind you are reporting.

You could use something like `\label{tab:aéa}`. But although this would not produce the same error, it is likely to cause other problems. It would be better by far to stick to `\label{tab:aea}`.

Comment: I am now getting this error with a simple _hyphen_ in the label name. This gets generated in my AUX: `\newlabel{scr:ui\unhbox \voidb@x \kern \z@ \char `\discretionary {-}{}{}waveform}`. Your explanation about special characters doesn't quite work here...

Comment: @MightyPork Please ask a question of your own which includes a complete but minimal example which reproduces the problem. For example, `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\label{k-1}\ref{k-2}
\kant[1]
\ref{k-1}
\kant[2]
\label{k-2}
\end{document}` works fine for me. No problems at all. The `.aux`, for example, includes `\newlabel{k-1}{{}{1}}` etc.

Comment: It appears to be a bug in Czech babel with no good workaround. Had 10 hours to google it some more..